# How can I improve the look of a window created in python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, raspberry-pi, lcd

I want to create a window that does not look like a window from windows xp.

I want a plain box with no bar on the top. Is this  possible?

I am trying to make a gui but I want a full screen fixed display. Btw I am using, or would like to use tkinter.

Answer (score 1):

you can import ttk and use different styles within tkinter and create your own custom theme but apart from that not unless you use a different module
(note ttk is a stock python module)

for example

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

mycolour = "color code here"
mybackground = "color code here"

style = ttk.Style()

style.theme_create( "custom_theme", parent="alt", settings={
    "TNotebook": {"configure": {"tabmargins": [2, 5, 2, 0] } },
    "TNotebook.Tab": {
        "configure": {"padding": [5, 1], "background": mycolour },
        "map":       {"background": [("selected", mybackground)],
                      "expand": [("selected", [1, 1, 1, 0])] } } } )


style.theme_use("custom_theme")
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your toplevel is named `toplevel`, you can use `wm_attributes` to make it full-screen:

```
toplevel.wm_attributes('-fullscreen', '1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do:

```
root.state('zoomed')
```

This would show it as a full screen app..